# How to get source code of native C language library used in java 1.4?

Tags: java, c, native, sun, crc32

I want to see implementation of java.util.zip.CRC32. But within this class its using native c library functions for core implementation.How can I get the native source code. I can see the java.util.zip.CRC32 source code, but this doesn't have the actual implementation.

Comment: __Copyright 2003 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved. * SUN PROPRIETARY/CONFIDENTIAL. Use is subject to license terms.__ It is perhaps unwise to post this code in a public forum.

Comment: its not containing actual core implementation.Thats why i did.But thanks for advice.

Comment: This is proprietary code. You cannot get the source code because it is not open source. Sun includes some of the source code with the JDK, but that doesn't make it open source. Only later versions of Sun's JDK are available as open source. http://www.opensource.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must ask SUN, I mean Oracle about having the source code...  :-/

You can try the source code for Java 6 at this [download page](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp). CRC32 should not have changed much between Java 1.4 and 6.

Answer (score 2):

Sun Java 1.4 is not open source.